# Move footer up for more text

Tags: header-footer, margins

I need to move the footer up because the text is pretty long and doesn't fit to it. And I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi T_T [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Have you looked at the `geometry` package?

Comment: Not yet. My experience with TeX is only a day.

Comment: in which case, [see the documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand the question. If the text was long I'd expect the footer to need to move *down* to make more space. In either case the space left for the footer is governed by `\footskip` so you can `\addtolength\footskip{1cm}` or `-2\baselineskip` or whatever length needed.

Comment: It's exactly what I need!

Comment: @David Carlisle: is `\baselinskip` a command I just don't know about? _That's_ the part I was trying to edit, but a single character is too little a change.

Comment: @twip ah sorry you could have highlighted that in a comment on the edit I thought you'd just re-arranged the english a bit, I'll fix